# Two Scripts are Conflicting - One that is second in order works - looking for solution

Tags: javascript

Here are the two scripts in question. Only the second will run. I can reverse them and whichever one is second will run. How can I resolve this conflict?

**SCRIPT 1**

```
<script>
function init() {
var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

**SCRIPT 2**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        richSnippetReviewsWidgets({
            store: "www-majorsafety-com",
            primaryClr: "#f47e27",
            widgetName: "floating-widget",
            numReviews: 40,
            floatPosition: "right",
            contentMode: "company;third-party",
            hideDates: false
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: you're replacing the onload...

Comment: Maybe have a flag in the page you are running them like `var haveIRun = false;`. Before running any of them, check if this is false. After the check passes, immediately make it true so the next function will read it as true and not run the code. Also, what is the priority here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one function set in `window.onload` for the page.

To work around this, just use `addEventListener`.

The first script becomes:

```
<script>
function init() {
var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.addEventListener('load', init)
</script>
```

The second script becomes:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        richSnippetReviewsWidgets({
            store: "www-majorsafety-com",
            primaryClr: "#f47e27",
            widgetName: "floating-widget",
            numReviews: 40,
            floatPosition: "right",
            contentMode: "company;third-party",
            hideDates: false
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ ... });
```

Add an event listener, otherwise `onload =` does a complete replace of any previous set to that single property.